# 18.04.5 Network stops working after a while

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, system on a AMD 64bit system with 16GB. Recent Zoneminder install has cranked up traffic. But I did not use this system much prior to the ZM install.

After a while (minutes to hours), the system stops communicating. When this happens, the ARP cache is mostly showing incomplete in the mac entries, and the only way to reset is to reboot or unplug the Ethernet. Eventually it happens again. I have tried 3 different drivers up to and including the latest from Realtek. Currently using the r8168, 8.045.08, 4.15.0-118-generic, x86_64 driver per dkms. No real diff between them. The systems I am trying to ping are all in the same local subnet. Interestingly, the default router, and other IP's that are not sending or receiving traffic, retain their macs in the arp cache UNTIL I try to ping them or otherwise communicate with them. So once this starts, every ARP entry will move to "incomplete" until no comms with anything is possible. To be clear all IP and ping traffic immediately fails, but the arp cache doesn't start to show Incompletes util I try to send or receive to each one. It makes sense to me why I can't communicate. The system does not know the mac! The question is why is ARP failing. Multiple other systems on the same local IP subnet have no issues communicating with these exact same external systems all on the same local switch. I have tried different switch ports, but after briefly correcting itself, it just happens again. I have no duplicate IP's. It is like ARP validation just goes to sleep along with periodic ARP flush. I am not sure what to look at next.

Any ideas why it keeps dropping? I see similar questions like mine here, but none say it was ever resolved and trying some of the suggestions did not help me.

Comment: I originally opened this question with less info and the WRONG version info.  I could not figure out how to delete that question when it was closed due to an old version that was incorrect..

Comment: Wow...nothing in 2 days??  Can anyone tell me how to look at arp processes or something??  I see other similar posts, and none seem resolved.  Am I missing something?